# is Service killed along with activity

Tags: android

Well this is kind of confusing.
1- Is a Service killed when the Activity that created it, is destroyed?
2- Will a Service keep on running when there's no activity bounded to it (when the app is closed)?
3- Services need an inner Thread to avoid ANR so, what's the meaning with Services then,     isn't it better to only use Threads?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read this...

[Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)

...in particular the section titled "Application Components" - it explains a great deal.